# How to print items in a list to a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, list, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am having troubles printing items of a list through a method into a JTextArea.

```
void grab(){

    if(appleField.getText().equals("")){
       appleField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int a = Integer.parseInt(appleField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(a, "Apples bought:"));
    }

    if(bananaField.getText().equals("")){
       bananaField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int b = Integer.parseInt(bananaField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(b, "Bananas bought:"));
    }

    if(cherryField.getText().equals("")){
       cherryField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int c = Integer.parseInt(cherryField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(c, "Cherries bought:"));
    }

    if(dukuField.getText().equals("")){
       dukuField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int d = Integer.parseInt(dukuField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(d, "Dukus bought:"));
    }

    if(elderField.getText().equals("")){
       elderField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int e = Integer.parseInt(elderField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(e, "Elderberries bought"));
    }

    if(falField.getText().equals("")){
       falField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int f = Integer.parseInt(falField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(f, "Falberries bought"));
    }

    if(gacField.getText().equals("")){
       gacField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int g = Integer.parseInt(gacField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(g, "Gacs bought"));
    }

    if(honeyField.getText().equals("")){
       honeyField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int h = Integer.parseInt(honeyField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(h, "Honeydews bought"));;
    }

    if(mangoField.getText().equals("")){
       mangoField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int m = Integer.parseInt(mangoField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(m, "Mangos bought"));
    }

    if(passionField.getText().equals("")){
       passionField.setText("");
    }
    else{
        int p = Integer.parseInt(passionField.getText());
        list.add(new MyShoppingCart(p, "Passion fruits bought"));
    }

}
```

It just parses each value then adds to list if it contains something.

And here is the method to "append".

```
void printList() {
    cartArea.setText("");
    for (MyShoppingCart s : list) {
        StringBuffer spaces = new StringBuffer("                    ");
        spaces.setLength(spaces.length() - s.getName().length());
        cartArea.append(s.getName() + spaces);
        cartArea.append(s.getQuantity() + "\n");
    }
}
```

I know the print statement is wrong, but its the only thing I have now.

Comment: Which "print statement" are you referring to? (Most often, in Java, "print statement" means `System.out.println` - but there is no such statement here.) And in what way is it wrong? What problem do you encounter?

Comment: Consider using a `JList` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a problem with formatting shopping items in the text area. Try using `String.format` to format each line properly, for example:

```
for (MyShoppingCart s : list) {
    cartArea.append(String.format("%-20s %-20s\n", s.getName(), s.getQuantity()));
}
```

Be sure to use a fixed width font, ie `Monospaced`:

```
Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14);
textArea.setFont(font);
```

As an alternative, consider using a different control altogether - `JTable`. It may be more suitable as it supports multiple columns. You can hide grid lines if needed. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for some examples.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that `JTextArea` uses a fixed width font by default...BUT...this may be Look and Feel dependent ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer true, it is L&F dependent. For `WindowsLookAndFeel` it is `Monospaced`; for `MetalLookAndFeel` it is `Dialog`.